# outlook vba swap recipients

Tags: vba, outlook

People often forward mails to me and ask me to reply to the original sender, who is in CC. I think it's more neat to put this person in the To field and the forwarder in CC. So I like to swap them. I came up with this piece of VBA:

```
Sub Swap()
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

With objMail
   a$ = .To
   .To = .CC
   .CC = a$
End With

Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the recipients are copied as text. So Outlook will search for them again in our company's address book. And as it is a large company, sometimes it finds the wrong person, or even claims a person is unknown.

I've experimented with objmail.Recipients but I only got some weird errors. Note: There might be multiple people in both the To and the CC field.

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the email address out of `objMail.Recipients(x).Address`. The following code works fine on my machine:

```
Public Sub Swap()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application ' i use this, because i'm working in MS Access
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objRecipient As Outlook.recipient
Dim strTo As String
Dim strCC As String

Set objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") ' i use this, because i'm working in MS Access
Set objMail = objOutlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

For Each objRecipient In objMail.Recipients ' here we loop through all recipients

    If objRecipient.type = olTo Then ' check if the current recipient is in To section
        strCC = strCC & ";" & objRecipient.Address ' add it to the CC string

    ElseIf objRecipient.type = olCC Then ' check if the current recipient is in CC section
        strTo = strTo & ";" & objRecipient.Address 'add it to the To string

    End If
Next objRecipient

If strTo <> "" Then
    objMail.To = MID(strTo, 2) ' we cut off the leading semicolon of our string
End If

If strCC <> "" Then
    objMail.CC = MID(strCC, 2) ' same here
End If

Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just change the Type property appropriately?

Comment: I've tried `If objRecipient.type = olTo Then objRecipient.type = olCC` but it didn't work. Maybe the `objMail.Recipients` has to be updated or the To and CC Textboxes just don't show the current value. I didn't get it to work that way. By generating a string it worked fine.

Comment: i opened a new e-mail, wrote "testTo@test.com" into the To-field and "testCC@test.com" into the CC-Field and ran the code, but nothing happened. The addresses didn't swap and there was no error message. Then i tried it with the strings and it worked fine.

Comment: I keep running into the same problem. I've tried going through all items and use type BCC as temporary storage (I never use it anyway). But nothing happens. I want to avoid using Resolve. I must say that Dorian's solution makes it unlikely that no or the wrong person is found.

Comment: I've added this line to your code:                        objMail.recipients.ResolveAll. Although I intended to swap the resolved items, I guess this is as good as it gets. So Dorian, I like to thank you for your answer. I will be using your solution. My 'reputation' isn't high enough yet to mark your answer as useful. But I consider this problem as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The [To](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860378(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class returns a semicolon-delimited string list of display names for the To recipients for the Outlook item. This property contains the display names only. Instead, the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866751.aspx) collection should be used to modify recipients.

You just need to get an instance of the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866751.aspx) collection, see the corresponsing property of the MailItem class which returns a collection of Recipient objects for an Outlook item. And then change the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863703.aspx) property of the entries.

Depending on the type of recipient, this property returns or sets an integer corresponding to the numeric equivalent of one of the following constants:

- JournalItem recipient: the OlJournalRecipientType constant olAssociatedContact.
- MailItem recipient: one of the following OlMailRecipientType constants: **olBCC**, **olCC**, olOriginator, or **olTo**.
- MeetingItem recipient: one of the following OlMeetingRecipientType constants: olOptional, olOrganizer, olRequired, or olResource.
- TaskItem recipient: either of the following OlTaskRecipientType constants: olFinalStatus, or olUpdate.